# How to hide copy/paste popup

Tags: android, view

can someone help me with Android system copy/paste popup? I want to hide it when a user clicks at some button because now popup overlaps drawer layout. But I need this popup. I just want to hide it when click drawer button.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by adding `mDrawerLayout.requestFocusFromTouch()` when opening drawer.

Answer (score 1):

Use **`android:longClickable="false"`** in your `editText` it will work

Comment: I need this popup, I only want to hide it, when press drawer button.

Answer (score 1):

There is something wrong with your design because when you create drawer, fragments rest behind the drawer. So that popup should not overlap above navigation drawer. You can find more stuff here https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this in onCreate :

```java
edittext.setLongClickable(false);
        edittext.setTextIsSelectable(false);
        edittext.setCustomSelectionActionModeCallback(new ActionMode.Callback() {
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
                return false;
                }
                public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode actionMode, Menu menu) {
                    return false;
                }
                public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode actionMode, MenuItem item) {
                    return false;
                }
                public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode actionMode) {
                }
            });
```